# How to deploy a report using Migration Tool?

Tags: deployment

I am trying to deploy a report with the XML file, but it does not work. The report is in a folder named Unfiled Public Reports and the report is named Actions Trimestre Type / Type. the problem is that i  can not get the api name of the folder and the report i tried many combinations in the xml file but nothing works,

```
     <types>
        <members>UnfiledPublicReports/ActionsTrimestreType/Type</members>
        <name>Report</name>
    </types>
```

Do you know how to do that properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic string you are looking for is `unfiled$public`.

You can read about it on our [blog](https://gearset.com/blog/comparing-salesforce-unfiled-reports).

You can also use our [free trial (1-click signup)](https://gearset.com) to move the report for you as should be easier and faster than using ant :)

Comment: Thanks very much, it works like a charm, concerning you offer, i will consider it when working just on reports but now i am working on bigger deployment process and ANT is suitable for that.

Comment: No problem, just for the record in case it is helpful to you, Gearset handles everything in the Metadata API and not only reports :)